# get user email of current user microsoft

Tags: php, shell, cmd

I'm trying to get user email of current user using command line. In Powershell i paste these lines and it works

```
>> $searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$env:USERNAME)"
>> $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("mail"))
>> $searcher.FindOne().Properties["mail"][0]
test@gmail.com
```

and in command line i tried these lines and its works to

```
>powershell.exe -e KABbAEEARABTAEkAXQAoACIATABEAEEAUAA6AC8ALwAiACAAKwAgACgAdwBoAG8AYQBtAGkAIAAvAGYAcQBkAG4AKQApACkALgBtAGEAaQBsAA==
test@gmail.com
```

but when i try to do these solutions in php with exec or shell_exec, it shows me nothing as result

```
//solution 1
$cmd=<<<'CMD'
$searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$env:USERNAME)" \
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("mail")) \
$searcher.FindOne().Properties["mail"][0]
CMD;

echo shell_exec($cmd);


//solution 2
$cmd=<<<'CMD'
powershell.exe -e KABbAEEARABTAEkAXQAoACIATABEAEEAUAA6AC8ALwAiACAAKwAgACgAdwBoAG8AYQBtAGkAIAAvAGYAcQBkAG4AKQApACkALgBtAGEAaQBsAA==
    CMD;
    
    echo exec($cmd);
```

i don't know if i have a syntaxe problem or it's not possible to get user email of current user microsoft using PHP

Comment: Did you try without CMD in your exec call ? Like : $cmd= '
powershell.exe -e KABbAEEARABTAEkAXQAoACIATABEAEEAUAA6AC8ALwAiACAAKwAgACgAdwBoAG8AYQBtAGkAIAAvAGYAcQBkAG4AKQApACkALgBtAGEAaQBsAA==';

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get the same result. I think PHP usually runs under a different user with it's own permission set.

Comment: yes, i've already tried this and unfortunately no result is shown

Comment: As I said on your other question, remove the back slashes from your commands in solution 1.

Comment: @RobRuchte i've already removed it and still have the same problem :/